# In a Facebook group on a post what does "seen by 3" mean?

Tags: facebook

I'm in a group and I posted something. Then, beneath my post it says "seen by 2" and when I click it, two users names are displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shows you how many people have seen/read it and (via the link) who they are.

It's a recent change (as of 28<sup>th</sup> August 2012) that's just been announced.

Here's a [Techcrunch article](http://techcrunch.com/2012/07/11/facebook-group-read-receipts/) that explains it in more detail.

Comment: This is sort of a silly feature. It sounds like it still counts if a post is at the bottom of a page, and people normally only read new posts towards the top.